# refactor map, reduce and double for loop - javascript es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript object, lets say `parentObj`.

> How can I improve the below code. I have a `reduce`, a `map` and a `double for loop`.

```
[
   {
      NAME: 'SOMENAME',
      ID: '1',
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
    },

   {
      NAME: 'SOMENAME',
      ID: '2',
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
   },

   {
      NAME: 'SOMENAME',
      ID: '3',
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
   }
]
```

I created a new object.

```
  const newObj = .reduce(
    function (obj, item) {
      obj[item.NAME] = obj[item.NAME] || [];
      obj[item.NAME].push(item.ID);
      return obj;
    },
    {}
  );
```

Then a new array of object out of it.

```
  const newObjArr = Object.keys(newObj ).map(function (key) {
        return { NAME: key, ID: newObj [key] };
      });
```

And then a double for loop.

```
      for (let item1 of newObjArr) {
        for (let item2 of parentObj) {
          if (item1.NAME=== item2.NAME) {
            finalObjArr.push({ NAME: item1.NAME, ID: item1.ID, FROM: item2.FROM, TO: item2.TO});
          }
        }
      }
```

My final output:

```
[
   {
      NAME: 'SOMENAME',
      ID: [1, 2, 3],
      FROM: '20191223',
      TO: '99991231'
   },
   ...
]
```

Comment: This sounds like you want to transform the input. Can you supply both example input and expected output?

Comment: What are you trying to reduce in the 2nd code snippet?

Comment: @Ben updated....

Comment: Are you sure you want some `ID` entries in your output to share the same array objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have that `newObj` where you can look up things by name. No need to build that `newObjArr` and loop over it to search by name. Just write

```
for (const item2 of parentObj) {
  const item1_NAME = item2.NAME;
  const item1_IDs = newObj[item1_NAME];
  finalObjArr.push({ NAME: item1_NAME, ID: item1_IDs, FROM: item2.FROM, TO: item2.TO});
}
```

---

Given your updates in the comments, I'd suggest you actually put your objects with all info in the `newObj`, then all you need to get are its values as an array:

```
const newObj = parentObj.reduce((obj, item) => {
  if (!(item.NAME in obj))
    obj[item.NAME] = { NAME: item.NAME, ID: [], FROM: item.FROM, TO: item.TO };
  obj[item.NAME].ID.push(item.ID);
  return obj;
}, {});
const finalObjArr = Object.values(newObj);
```

Comment: This output could differ in order from the OP's output when the `parentObj` array does not have all entries with the same `NAME` values as consecutive items.

Comment: @trincot Ah, that's true. If order is important, they shouldn't have use `Object.keys` though :-)

Comment: @Bergi, how can I ensure duplicate `NAME` is not entered.

Comment: @user2281858 There are duplicate names if the `item1_IDs` array has more than one element

Comment: @Bergi can i simply not create the `final array of object` from `parentObject` That way I can also avoid the duplicates, cuz in the `reduce` function, I have made sure there are no duplicates.

Comment: @user2281858 I don't understand. Your original code with the double loops did output the duplicates as well, didn't it? Even if their names are duplicate, the `FROM` and `TO` might not.

Comment: `FROM` and `TO` for will be constant per name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```js
// sample data
let parentObj = [{NAME: 'SOMENAME',ID: '1',FROM: '20171223',TO: '99991231'},{NAME: 'SOMENAME',ID: '2',FROM: '20181223',TO: '99991231'},{NAME: 'SOMENAME',ID: '3',FROM: '20191223',TO: '99991231'}];

let map = new Map(parentObj.map(o => [o.NAME, []]));
parentObj.forEach(o => map.get(o.NAME).push(o));
let finalObjArr = Array.from(map.values(), arr => 
     arr.map(o => ({...o, ID: arr.map(o => o.ID)}))
).flat();

console.log(finalObjArr);
```

The difference with your own solution is that each `ID` array in the output will now be independent. So if you would mutate one, that change would not show up in another object.

I used `array.flat()` which is not in ES6 (you mentioned ES6). If that is an issue, then use `[].concat(...array)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want.

```js
const parentObj = [{
    NAME: 'SOMENAME',
    ID: '1',
    FROM: '20191223',
    TO: '99991231'
},
{
    NAME: 'SOMENAME',
    ID: '2',
    FROM: '20191223',
    TO: '99991231'
},
{
    NAME: 'SOMENAME',
    ID: '3',
    FROM: '20191223',
    TO: '99991231'
}]

const ids = parentObj.reduce((p,{NAME, ID})=>
        ((p[NAME] || (p[NAME] = [])),
         (p[NAME].push(ID)), p), {})

console.log(parentObj.map(({NAME, FROM, TO})=>
        ({NAME, ID: ids[NAME], FROM, TO})))
```

Or this might be what you want. There was a possibility of ambiguity based on your comment on another answer:

```js
const parentObj = [{
    NAME: 'SOMENAME',
    ID: '1',
    FROM: '20191223',
    TO: '99991231'
},
{
    NAME: 'SOMENAME',
    ID: '2',
    FROM: '20191223',
    TO: '99991231'
},
{
    NAME: 'SOMENAME',
    ID: '3',
    FROM: '20191223',
    TO: '99991231'
}]

console.log(Object.values(parentObj.reduce(
    (p,{NAME, ID, FROM, TO})=>
        ((p[NAME] || (p[NAME] = {NAME, ID: [], FROM, TO})),
         (p[NAME]['ID'].push(ID)), p), {})))
```

Comment: i m not able to run `[...p[NAME]`. It says this syntax requires an imported helper named _spreadArrays